# How can I change the download server for updates?

Tags: server, upgrade, updates

I continuously failed to upgrade my Ubuntu from 11.04 to 12.04.

I tried running these commands:

- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `do-release-upgrade`

But none of them work.

The error they give is usually one of these:

- `failed to fetch ...`
- `Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
- `Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager.`

I searched from this site, and just that it could be coming from update server. People recommended to edit in Ubuntu Software Center, from "main server" to "best server" or "server of US'... But I can't find these options in my software center.

But my Ubuntu Software Center is not providing any menus like that, instead, it seems like just download center like App store of mac.

How can I change the download server for update of my machine?

ps) sudo update-manager gives following error

```
WARNING: can not get name for '<CellRendererText object at 0x22670a0 (GtkCellRendererText at 0x23ff150)>'
WARNING: can not get name for '<TextBuffer object at 0x233c550 (GtkTextBuffer at 0x1d95100)>'

mirror: mirror.umoss.org - time: 0.139289855957
mirror: www.club.cc.cmu.edu - time: 0.146475076675
mirror: mirrors.acm.jhu.edu - time: 0.1808989048
mirror: linux.ntuoss.org - time: 0.18235206604
mirror: ubuntu.cybercomhosting.com - time: 0.862604856491
mirror: ftp.tku.edu.tw - time: 1.88249111176
and the winner is: mirror.umoss.org
WARNING: can not get name for '<CellRendererText object at 0x1f21c80 (GtkCellRendererText at 0x2169150)>'
WARNING: can not get name for '<TextBuffer object at 0x2098d70 (GtkTextBuffer at 0x1aff100)>'
authenticate 'oneiric.tar.gz' against 'oneiric.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'oneiric.tar.gz'
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file
```

Please somebody help me :(

Comment: @mikewhatever, He's apparently trying to upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04, so the issues that he's having are irrelevant to what he wants to do. I don't think it's a duplicate of that question, however, the first answer _might_ help what he's trying to do (if the update manager is being particularity annoying)